# What is the difference between graphic api and rendering engine

Tags: api, opengl, rendering, render, vulkan

What is the actual difference between graphic api like openGl or Vulkan and rendering engine like evee or octane render.

Which one can be used to create game engines.

Comment: Rendering engine probably uses cross-platform graphics libraries, so one level of abstraction higher. They can all be used to create game engines, depending on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics API is the way for you to tell your GPU what to do;
Rendering engines are systems that define certain rules about how to draw things.
The difference is like difference between game engines, and languages on which those were written